# Picard Iterations for general polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am currently writing a program in R to find solutions of a general polynomial difference equation. But I got stuck doing so, as I am unable to find a recurring theme in the calculations of the following iteration, as I want to write the program for n iterations.

Using Picard's method I try to estimate the solution of the equation:

$x'(t) = \sum^m_{j=0} a_j x(t)^j$ for $t\ge0$

Where I use
$x(0) = x_0$, $F(x(t)) = \sum^m_{j=0} a_j x(t)^j$

Now the first few iterations results in

$x_0 = x_0$, where $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$

$x_1 = x_0 + \int_0^t \sum^m_{j=0} a_j x_0^j ds = x_0 + \sum^m_{j=0} a_j x_0^j t$

Defining $z = \sum^m_{j=0} a_j x_0^j$

$x_2 = x_0 + \int_0^t \sum^m_{j=0} a_j x_1^j ds = x_0 + \int_0^t \sum^m_{j=0} a_j (x_0 + zt)^j ds = x_0 + \sum^m_{j=0} a_j \frac{(x_0 + zs)^{j+1}}{(1+j)z} $

$x_3 = x_0 + \int_0^t \sum^m_{i=0} a_i x_2^i ds = x_0 + \int_0^t \sum^m_{i=0} a_i (x_0 + \sum^m_{j=0} a_j \frac{(x_0 + zs)^{j+1}}{(1+j)z})^i ds$

And at this point I get stuck on the iterating process. I've tried continuing using things like the binomial theorem, but without success. Now my main questions considering this are:

Is there another way of continuing without writing out all terms using e.g. the binomial theorem?

Am I following any over-complicated/incorrect steps and/or is there a way to simplify the problem?

Am I failing to see a pattern which I can apply to find further iterations?

Thanks a lot in advance.